# AWS Glue - Retain leading zeros while processing XML files

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, schema, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have XML files stored in s3 bucket and crawler runs to generate schema in catalog tables.
Catalog tables are generated but when i check the output in AWS Glue Studio,
I could see the data that starts with zeros are getting eliminated.
eg: 00034325 => 34325
Even conversion of catalog table schema datatype from int to string doesn't resolve this issue.

Kindly let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Within the script that's generated by AWS Glue Studio, you may want to ensure that the column you're expecting to be a string is actually defined as such and not as a numeric type.  You might see something like the following: `applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("source", "string", "destination", "number")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")` which maps from source string to destination number.

Comment: Hi @Norman Thanks for your reply.
I tried with above mapping method. But still leading zeros are getting eliminated.
My issue is with the integer type values for which leading zeros are dropped.
I tried converting to string for destination value but it didn't work.
Even i tried to convert the destination value to long type still the same issue.
I am not sure how to resolve this in AWS Glue.
Let me know if there are any alternatives.

Comment: If the Data catalog defines the data as a string and the destination is defined as a string, it should work, my only concern is that somewhere within the generated script you have a mapping to number.  Please note that existing data in the destination won't necessarily be updated after modifying the catalog to string so please refer to newly imported data to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

This is a crawler bug. Nothing to do with the mapping in the glue. Crawler infers the type first, glue job only consumes the result of that. As far as I know there is no way to change the incoming type which crawler came up with - quite an annoying issue. The only option I can think of is to pre-process data before it gets to the bucket and escape the value to be a string before crawler get's to crawl it.